# Modal or New page for "Configuration area"

Tags: information-architecture, modal

I'm sketcking a new tool. I have a litle problem. All tool is in the same view, like a Dashboard. Now, I have to prepare the "Configure area".

I have been searching examples about this (Modal or New Page), the 90% of the examples use modal in this case.

**Which is the best option and why?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A modal will work better if those options are just for that page. For example:

- If you have a table that has customisable columns, you could have a modal pop up that allows the user to select which columns they want to see.

A separate page works best when the options are site wide. For example:

- An option to change the colors of graphs to better suit a user with color deficiency.
- Setting defaults that will be used throughout the site.